# Confused about creating a sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm writing a java code using POI, the aim here is to create sheets and add data into it. and the criteria is as below.

I've a text file with a set of keywords like below.

```
MainOne
MainTwo
```

And I'm looping the available sheets and creating a sheet based on this key word.

if there is no key word match, I want to add a sheet named `no keyword` to the workbook. and on each iteration, check if the sheet with keyword is available, if so use it, if not create a sheet.

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("KeyWords.txt"));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            BasicExcel.createACell(line);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

**BasicExcel Class**

```
public static void createACell(String keyWord) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Test\\new.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);
        int noOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        HSSFSheet sheet = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfSheets; j++) {
            if (!workbook.getSheetName(j).equalsIgnoreCase("No KeyWords")) {
               sheet = workbook.createSheet("No KeyWords");
            } else if (!workbook.getSheetName(j).equalsIgnoreCase(keyWord)) {
               sheet = workbook.createSheet(keyWord);
            } else {
               sheet = workbook.getSheet(keyWord);
            }
        }
        input_document.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Test\\new.xls"));
        try {
            workbook.write(out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.close();
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

when I run this program, I'm getting the below Exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a
>   sheet named 'Insurance'   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:877)
>     at BasicExcel.createACell(BasicExcel.java:22)   at
>   EmailTestWithScanner.readEmails(EmailTestWithScanner.java:115)    at
>   EmailTestWithScanner.main(EmailTestWithScanner.java:137)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a
>   sheet named 'MMS'     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:877)
>     at BasicExcel.createACell(BasicExcel.java:22)   at
>   EmailTestWithScanner.readEmails(EmailTestWithScanner.java:115)    at
>   EmailTestWithScanner.main(EmailTestWithScanner.java:137)

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Only create the sheet at the end of your loop

Comment: @Gagravarr, you mean the `while` or the `for`?

Comment: The for loop over the sheets

Comment: Don't create a new sheet until you've finished checking all of them. At the moment, you're creating a new sheet if the first one doesn't match

Comment: @Gagravarr, I'm still a bit confused about creating at the end after checking, what should I modify here `for (int j = 0; j < noOfSheets; j++) {
   if (!workbook.getSheetName(j).equalsIgnoreCase("No KeyWords")) {
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("No KeyWords");
   } else if (!workbook.getSheetName(j).equalsIgnoreCase(keyWord)) {
    sheet = workbook.createSheet(keyWord);
   } else {
    sheet = workbook.getSheet(keyWord);
   }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You should check first if a sheet with the same name already exists using [`getSheetIndex(String name)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getSheetIndex(java.lang.String)).

If it returns `-1`, it would mean that it doesn't exist yet so you would be able to call `createSheet(String sheetname)` safely otherwise you would be able to use `getSheetAt(int index)` to retrieve the corresponding `HSSFSheet` instance.

Here is the pseudo code that shows the idea:

```
int index = workbook.getSheetIndex("No KeyWords");
HSSFSheet sheet;
if (index == -1) {
    // It doesn't exist yet so let's create it
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("No KeyWords");
} else {
    // It already exists so let's get it
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but this appears to take a lot of time to process :(

Comment: You have to do it many times ? If so put your HSSFSheet in a map with the sheet name as key and the related HSSFSheet as value and get your `HSSFSheet` instances from your map